# How can I get Visual Studio (Mac) to meet GitHub Token Authentication requirements?

Tags: github, visual-studio-mac

I recently committed to GitHub using Visual Studio for Mac (8.10.6) and got an email:

> You recently used a password to access the repository at
>  with git using git/2.24.3 (Apple Git-128).
>
> Basic authentication using a password to Git is deprecated and will
> soon no longer work. Visit
> https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/
> for more information around suggested workarounds and removal dates.

I've read that blog post but I cannot see how to make this change for VS. I note that it mentioned `git/2.24.3` but from the command-line I see:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.10.0
$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git
```

**Update**
On a new machine, I am indeed prompted for login details and can use a PAT. But I would still love to know where this is stored on disk, or in VS settings, in case I need to *change* Git user.

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac stores Git username and passwords in the macOS Keychain. I would try searching in the Keychain Access app and delete that key. Another alternative here would be to use ssh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use personal access tokens. Click on your profile picture on the GitHub page, then on **Settings → Personal access tokens → Generate new token**. Follow the wizard to select what to grant, at least you'll need to read repo.

On Visual Studio Code you provide your username and for password, you provide the newly generated personal access token.

P.s: Make sure to note down the personal access token somewhere.

Comment: I cannot see where I can set/change it in VS... it has my password saved somewhere I guess. I could wait until GitHub stops accepting passwords but I would rather preempt this.

Comment: A note for anyone coming to this answer in 2023 or later: PAT generation seems to have moved to Settings → Developer Settings  → Personal access tokens, and "fine grained" tokens seem to be preferred to classic tokens. See https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token